# Swift 5.1 Can I access a struct instance declaration in another view controller?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, struct, uiviewcontroller, swift5

I have a struct:

```
struct User {
var name: String = ""
}
```

Then I created an instance of the struct in view controller 1

```
var user = User()
```

Assigned a value to it in view controller 1

```
user.name = "John"
```

How do I copy the value "John" in another view controller using the struct instance?
My main goal is to use structs in the MVC design pattern.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a multitude of ways. First I would say if you are passing it to a detail view controller then use preparForSegue method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "someSegue" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! YourDetailVC
        vc.user = self.user
    }
}
```

For other ways of passing data, you should research call backs, delegation, and  Notification Center.

Also structs automatically come with a memberwise initializer. So you can initialize it as follows:

```
let user = User(name: "John")
```